# Field containing date and time is not compared to another in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I'm trying to put a condition in the below query where the created date/time has to be greater than date/time of another field.
The condition is not taking affect and the result is not filtered.

```
    ->whereDate('posts.created_at','>','usrusrs.created_at')
```

I think it is comparing the date only, not date/time. Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to compare two fields of the same type you should use a simple `whereRaw()`:

```
->whereRaw('posts.created_at > usrusrs.created_at')
```

Or better with a `whereColumn()`:

```
->whereColumn('posts.created_at', '>', 'usrusrs.created_at')
```

The `whereDate()` function is to compare with a **value**. i.e.:

```
->whereDate('created_at', '2016-12-31')
```